# disable single variation if user is in specific group

Tags: woocommerce

i have a product with 6 variations of Membership (MEMBER, SPECIALMEMBER, NOMEMBER...)
it is possible to enable or disable purchase of this whole product (all variations), if the logged in user is in member group "specialmembers".

```
if ( user_can( $current_user, "specialmember" )) {
     return true;
     }
else {
     return true;
     }
```

How is it possible to disable just one single variation (MEMBER) für this user group?

Thank you very much for helping a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using any one of these hook tags you can disable particular variations.

1. `woocommerce_available_variation`
2. `woocommerce_variation_is_active`

### Solution 1

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_available_variation',
    function ( $data, $product, $variation ) {

        if ( 'green' === strtolower( $variation->get_attribute( 'pa_color' ) ) ) {
            $data['variation_is_active'] = false;
        }

        return $data;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```

### Solution 2

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_variation_is_active',
    function( $data, $variation ) {
        if ( 'green' === strtolower( $variation->get_attribute( 'pa_color' ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $data;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

In both solution we checking if the variation attribute `pa_color` is `green` if so then disable that option by assigning `false` for the variation active property.

As a result that variation will be disabled as represented in the given below image.
[image: Conditionally disabled variation]

### Filter Hook Source Code

[woocommerce_available_variation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L364)

[woocommerce_variation_is_active](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php#L561)

Comment: Thank you very much for your Reply, really appreciate!

its very close to what i want...
Now the Variation is grayed out, what is much better than now :)

Do you know a way, just to deactivate the "add to card button" in this variation which should stay active to choose?

Comment: Welcome, I hope this solution resolve your issue.

Comment: i have edited my comment, sorry.

Very close to what i want!

Possible to let the Variation active and just disable the add to card button / function instead?

Comment: The thing which you asked in comment is onChange event based control i.e. when a particular variation attribute selected show/hide add to cart button. As far my knowledge WooCommerce not provide any direct hook customization for this. Yes, this hiding cart button is possible but it requires lots of JS customization.

Comment: ok, lets leave it as it is... :)
Let me thank you very much again! Works like a charm.